# It is possible to reduce the size of a timePicker?

Tags: android, timepicker

I have to use two timepickers on my app, but they are so many big

there is a way to reduce the size of timepickers?

Comment: You may want to post this question in the android enthusiast exchange as well. http://android.stackexchange.com/ I am curious as to the solution to this problem too, i was unable to find a solution for this problem anywhere when i had this problem.

Comment: i did it but no one answers xD

Comment: prolink007, check this answer ---> http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2755/it-is-possible-to-reduce-the-size-of-a-timepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i decided to use a personalized timepicker